# Is it possible to use WebMatrix WebSecurity with Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory, webmatrix

We have intranet website created with .NET MVC 5.

This system uses WebMatrix WebSecurity class to manage authentication is MSSQL database.

User names in the database matches usernames in AD, but passwords are currently stored in the DB table.

Business raised requirement to authenticate users using passwords stored in active directory.

Can we switch to lookup user passwords in AD easily? How about role management?